# Image max-width in post with justified alignement

Tags: css, wordpress, post

I've defined blog post alignment as justified in my single.php. Problem now is that all images are being expanded to the full width of the blog post content of 700px. Some of the pictures I'm using in my blog posts aren't 700px wide though and now they are being stretched.

Is there any way I can define max-width just for single post images, when images are being added through the Add Media function?

I simply thought I could do the following:

```
<a href="....."><img class="wp-image-... alignnone" src="......" max-width="343" height="229" /></a>
```

But that doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#single img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="single">

  <img src="pic.jpg" alt="image"/>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Orcun, thanks, but that defines a whole set of images, doesn't it? I rather would like to change the max width settings on an image to image basis so to say, in each post for each picture differently.

Comment: you want it to fit on the screen for all widths, right? i edited code..

Comment: No I actually want to adjust the max-width for every picture separately, preferably in the visual editor, plain text editor. Hope that makes sense.